# How to update Products inventory from 3rd party POS system in Magento2?

Tags: api, magento, pos

How to update Products inventory from 3rd party POS system in Magento2?
I need to make a button in POS system when I hit that button the products inventory should be update from POS to Magento2 system.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code for update qty from Rest API

```
<?php $adminUrl = 'http://localhost/magento2/rest/V1/integration/admin/token/';
$ch = curl_init(); 
$data = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "admin"); //Admin Login details
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init($adminUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)));
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$token= json_decode($token);
$headers = array("Authorization: Bearer $token","Content-Type: application/json");
$skus = array('100001' => 66,'100002' => 99); //Here 100001 and 100002 are SKU and 66 and 99 are Qty
foreach ($skus as $sku => $stock) {
$requestUrl='http://localhost/magento2/rest/V1/products/' . $sku . '/stockItems/1';
$sampleProductData = array("qty" => $stock);
$productData = json_encode(array('stockItem' => $sampleProductData));
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $requestUrl);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $productData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($response);
unset($productData);
unset($sampleProductData);
}
```